# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^2\left(\frac{1-i}{2+i}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Does this sequence converge/diverge and  if so, does it in a (not)absolute way?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^2\left(\frac{1-i}{2+i}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z:=\frac{1-i}{2+i}=\frac{1-3i}5\implies |z|=\sqrt\frac25$$

and thus by the ratio test

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{(n+1)^2\sqrt{(2/5)^{n+1}}}{n^2\sqrt{(2/5)^n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\sqrt\frac25\;\;\ldots$$

Comment: I dont understand the first line, shouldnt it be $$\left(\frac{1-i}{2+1}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{2-i}{2-i}\right)
=\frac{(1-i)(2-i)}{(2+i)(2-i)}
=\frac{2-i-2i+i}{4-2i+2i-i^2}
=\frac{2-i}{5}$$ ? How can you derive the absolute value of $z$ from that fraction?

Comment: @sj134, check the following: $$(1-i)(2-i)=2-i-2i+i^2=2-3i-1=1-3i$$ $$\left|\frac15-\frac35i\right|=\sqrt{\frac1{25}+\frac9{25}}=\sqrt{\frac{10}{25}}=\sqrt\frac25$$ and good you asked something as I realize now I forgot a square root...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is the modulus of $(1-i)/(2+i).$

Comment: Absolute value.